# Policy based authorization gives InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-6.0

I have to add policy based authentication to my .net 6 webapp.
I added

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
     options.AddPolicy(Constants.Policies.RequireGlobalAdminRole, policy => policy.RequireRole(Constants.Roles.GlobalAdmin));
 });
```

to the program.cs file and in the dashboard controller I have decorated

```
 [Authorize(Policy = Constants.Policies.RequireGlobalAdminRole)]
```

In the after login, I created the claim for the role

```
                 var claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,Data.User.Role.RoleName)
                    };
                    var Identity=new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
                    ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal=new ClaimsPrincipal(Identity);.
```

But after successfull login, this error occurs.

> InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and
> there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be
> set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or
> AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an authentication scheme. For example (if you are using OIDC):

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
   options.DefaultScheme = "WebAuthScheme";
   options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
```

Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#authentication-scheme

Comment: I added  this on my program.cs. Still the error is there when redirecting to Dashboard controller

Answer (score 0):

Authorization happened after the authentication, and that's why you need to sign in first. The whole progress should be: user signed in, and as you said you created the claim for the signed in user, then you added an authorization policy , finally you added the `[Authorize(Policy = "policy_name")]` for a Controller or an action. According your error message, it should be missing authentication scheme. So let me provide you an sample. You can also refer to [this blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cookie-authentication-in-asp-net-core/) and [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

I used cookie authentication in my .net 6 sample. First, in `Program.cs` I need to define the authentication and authorization.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCookie(x => x.LoginPath = "/account/login");
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("mypolicy", policy =>
    {
        //I required the signed in usr must have role claim and the value must be Admin
        policy.RequireRole(new string[] { "Admin" });
    });
});
// don't forget to add use authentication
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Then we need an account controller, in this sample account controller provides the users to sign in:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Security.Claims;
using WebAppMvcCookieAuthAad.Models;

namespace WebAppMvcCookieAuthAad.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        //Sample Users Data, it can be fetched with the use of any ORM    
        public List<UserModel> users = null;
        public AccountController()
        {
            users = new List<UserModel>();
            users.Add(new UserModel()
            {
                UserId = 1,
                Username = "Tiny",
                Password = "123",
                Role = "Admin"
            });
            users.Add(new UserModel()
            {
                UserId = 2,
                Username = "Other",
                Password = "123",
                Role = "User"
            });
        }
        public IActionResult Login(string ReturnUrl = "/")
        {
            LoginModel objLoginModel = new LoginModel();
            objLoginModel.ReturnUrl = ReturnUrl;
            return View(objLoginModel);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel objLoginModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = users.Where(x => x.Username == objLoginModel.UserName && x.Password == objLoginModel.Password).FirstOrDefault();
                if (user == null)
                {
                    //Add logic here to display some message to user    
                    ViewBag.Message = "Invalid Credential";
                    return View(objLoginModel);
                }
                else
                {
                    //A claim is a statement about a subject by an issuer and    
                    //represent attributes of the subject that are useful in the context of authentication and authorization operations.    
                    var claims = new List<Claim>() {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, Convert.ToString(user.UserId)),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role),
                        new Claim("FavoriteDrink", "Tea")
                };
                    //Initialize a new instance of the ClaimsIdentity with the claims and authentication scheme    
                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    //Initialize a new instance of the ClaimsPrincipal with ClaimsIdentity    
                    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                    //SignInAsync is a Extension method for Sign in a principal for the specified scheme.    
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, new AuthenticationProperties()
                    {
                        IsPersistent = objLoginModel.RememberLogin
                    });
                    return LocalRedirect(objLoginModel.ReturnUrl);
                }
            }
            return View(objLoginModel);
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> LogOut()
        {
            //SignOutAsync is Extension method for SignOut    
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            //Redirect to home page    
            return LocalRedirect("/");
        }

        public IActionResult AadLogin() {
            return RedirectToAction("SignIn", "Account", new { area = "MicrosoftIdentity" });
        }
    }
}
```

Related models, `LoginModel` and `UserModel`:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WebAppMvcCookieAuthAad.Models
{
    public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Username")]
        public string UserName{get;set;}

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password{get;set;}

        public bool RememberLogin{get;set;}

        public string ReturnUrl{get;set;}
    }
    
    public class UserModel
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then the login page `View/Account/Login.cshtml`:

```
@model WebAppMvcCookieAuthAad.Models.LoginModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Login</h2>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Login">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Message))
            {
                <span class="text-danger">
                    @ViewBag.Message
                </span>
            }
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ReturnUrl)
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input asp-for="RememberLogin" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RememberLogin)
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then create a `_LoginPartial.cshtml` then add it to the `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@using System.Security.Principal

<ul class="navbar-nav">
    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <span class="navbar-text text-dark">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</span>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogOut">log out</a>
        </li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">log in</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

[image]

Finally, add the policy to the home controller：

```
[Authorize(Policy = "mypolicy")]
public class HomeController : Controller {}
```