# Permission checking to each action

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-6.0

In my .Net core application I want to set permissions to controller actions.
For example,

```
  public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.FirstName = HttpContext.Session.GetString("FirstName");
            ViewBag.LastName = HttpContext.Session.GetString("LastName");
            return View();
        }
```

this the action method in dashboard controller. It canbe read,write,update,special permissions. On login I will get all the modules and permissions to the logged user. So what will be the best way to check the logged user has permission to it.

Comment: Use `AutorizeAttribute`? =)

Comment: Using [policy based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0) authentication and authorization will be a good option for you. I have a detailed [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73903441/15581227) here.

Comment: how to pass attributes to these policies ?

Comment: I can't understand your question. pass attributes to policy? why you need to pass attribute to policy? policy defines that something is required, if you use the policy in controller or action, then the request should obey the policy then it can reach the controller or action.